# How to use 3TB HDD with BIOS PC?

Tags: hard-drive, bios

I'm buying a couple 3TB HDDs, but my PC has BIOS, and honestly, I have no clue how to get them to work (with only 1 partition)

Not sure what OS I'll use, either Windows 7/8 or Linux.

Comment: BIOS does not support booting to a storage device larger then 2TB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. Either use a third (smaller then 2TB) drive to boot from and use the 3TB drives for storage. (A small SSD would be perfect for this).
2. Use something like [discwizard](http://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/beyond-2tb/) software to work around it.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I didn't think it was relevant, but I plan on booting from a 60GB drive and using two 3TB drives for media. ^_^

Comment: In that case both Linux and windows 7 should be able to use them without any problems. Just as long as they are not the boot device.